# customize ssh command in ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to customize the ssh command in ubuntu using the ~/.bash_aliases file, basically I want to use the command 'zssh |$value|' to do: ssh root@name|$valuegoeshere|.hostname.org, I have tried to use this code:

```
function zssh{ssh root@name$1.hostname.org}
```

However I got the following error:

> bash: /home/amirs/.bash_aliases: line 1: syntax error near unexpected
>   token `root@name$1.hostname.org}' bash: /home/amirs/.bash_aliases:
>   line 1:`function zssh{ssh root@name$1.hostname.org}'

Any suggestions on how to configure the following function?

Comment: You need a space between the function name and `{`.

Comment: After the space I got the following error:

bash: /home/amirs/.bash_aliases: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `{ssh'

bash: /home/amirs/.bash_aliases: line 1: `function zssh {ssh root@name$1.hostname.org}'

Comment: add a space around each `{ and }` char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to define a function is:

```
zssh () {
    ssh root@name$1.hostname.org
}
```

The `function` keyword is optional and a bash extension, so there's no need to use it. You need whitespace around the `{` character, and there has to be a command delimiter (either newline or `;`) before `}`.